# which one to use? "pin" or "pind"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I work in an international company and my project manager told me that he will give me a pin(d) in my time log so I can register my working hours **(a row in my timelog that refers to the project that I've worked on)**. I just wonder if I've heard him correctly and if it is right in English since he is not a native speaker.

I've searched the word and found [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pind).

```
to put (stray cattle) in a pound
```

But then I don't know if it can be applied in the computer world

Comment: I wonder if they (is your PM a 'she' or a 'he'?) is using an acronym for a project ID or other item specific to your time keeping system (PND?). There's no English word that I can think of that sounds like 'pind' that would commonly be used in that context. I would ask your project manager about it.

Comment: She gave me a pin=Personal Identification Number. Maybe in that company it's called a PIN D or something like that.

Comment: Especially in AmE, a ***pin*** can be a badge, brooch, name tag, or similar (attached to clothing by a pin). Perhaps your manager is figuratively extending the usage to mean ***an identifying (text) label***, but given she's not a native speaker I doubt there's much point in speculating. Ask her. Note that your "cattle" sense relates to ***pen***, not ***pin***.

Comment: If the manager thinks in terms of spreadsheets / databases, she might be thinking in terms of [pivot views](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-views-in-an-Access-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752), which can be thought of as "rotating" around the user-selected central "pin".